# mdadm - Can't get RAID5 Array To Start

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm, ubuntu-10.04

after a power failure my RAID array refuses to start. When I boot I have to

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1
```

to get mdadm to notice the array.

Here are the details (after I force assemble).

**sudo mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md0:**

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 00.90
  Creation Time : Sun Apr 25 01:39:25 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1465135872 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 6
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Jun 17 23:02:38 2010
          State : active, Not Started
 Active Devices : 6
Working Devices : 6
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

           UUID : 44a8f730:b9bea6ea:3a28392c:12b22235 (local to host hodge-fs)
         Events : 0.1249691

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       65        0      active sync   /dev/sde1
       1       8       81        1      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       2       8       97        2      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       3       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       4       8       33        4      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       5       8       17        5      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

**mdadm.conf:**

```
# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb1

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5 num-devices=6 UUID=44a8f730:b9bea6ea:3a28392c:12b22235
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue  --run

Since you didn't use --scan, which will search your config file for any missing data it needs,  mdadm won't automatically start the array.

After getting it running, make a backup of /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, then run:

```
/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

which would recreate your mdadm.conf file with the array data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot - RAID is back up and syncing and I have fixed my mdadm.conf.

Much apperciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Why in the mdadm.conf you have only 2 devices but your raid uses 6 partitions.
Try to add all 6 devices to the mdadm.conf.

Comment: Thanks, I manually added the devices to mdadm.conf so now my file and then I was able to use sudo mdadm --run /dev/md0